# Need to get indexes from array and output them to user in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

We're displaying five input fields to user. He can type some information in them. After that, we need to find out if his input is correct. For that purpose we use an array of possible correct values. 
Like:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
input = input.toLowerCase();
inputPos = possibleInputs.indexOf(input);
inputPosArray.push(inputPos);
```

The code for analysis looks like that for now:

```
function arrayLookup() {
    var inputCorrect = true;
    inputPosArray.forEach(function(item, i, inputPosArray) {
        if (inputPosArray[i] == -1) {
            wrongInput = cardRPos.indexOf(cardRPos[i]) + 1;
            wrongInputsArray.push(wrongInput);
            inputCorrect = false;
    } else {
        null;
    }
    });
    if (inputCorrect == false) {
        alert("Wrong input! Check field " + wrongInputsArray);
    } else {
        nextStep();
    }}
```

For now it correctly finds out if input is wrong and alerts user. 
The problem is in "wrongInputsArray" - it doesn't display output correctly. E.g. if user has typed wrong information in 2nd field, it will print out "2".
But if he has made mistakes in 2nd and 5th field, he gets "Wrong input! Check field 2,2" alert. 
Please show me what am I doing wrong.

Kindly yours,
Richard

Comment: please add some more (missing) data, because it looks like that you have only one input, but an array for inputpos, which makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry to forget mention it. In this case it works for 5 inputs. The idea was to create a common module, which can be useful with any amount of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this code to insert the wrong asnwers:

`wrongInput = cardRPos.indexOf(cardRPos[i]) + 1;`

If two questions has the same answer, `indexOf` will return always the first match. Try just using this:

`wrongInput = i + 1;`

Comment: Looks like that helps. Thank you very much!